# How to calculate the value of the series limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {1^{\rm{ - }}}} \left\{ {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\widetilde{H_n^3}}}{{n + 1}}} {x^{n + 1}} + {{\ln }^3}2\ln \left( {1 - x} \right)} \right\} = ?.$$
where $$\widetilde{{H_n}} = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{k - 1}}}}{k}} .$$

Comment: The limit exists, but calculating it seems tricky.  Where did you come across this problem?

Comment: I'm in the calculation of the following series of problems$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{H_n}L_n^2\left( 1 \right)}}{n}} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{n - 1}}$, where ${H_n} = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}} ,{L_n}\left( 1 \right) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{k - 1}}}}{k}} .$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phantom{}_A H_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}$. Then, by summation by parts:

$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\phantom{}_A H_n^3-\log^3(2)}{n+1} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(H_{n+1}-1)}{n+1}\left(_A H_{n+1}^2+ _A\! H_{n+1}\,_A H_{n}+_A H_{n}^2\right)$$
where the RHS is convergent by Dirichlet's test. In order to compute its actual value we may exploit
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1} \phantom{}_A H_n\, x^n = \frac{\log(1+x)}{1-x} $$
and compute through it the following Taylor series:
$$ g(x)=(1-x)\cdot\sum_{n\geq 1} \phantom{}_A H_n^2\,x^n $$
by exploiting:
$$ \phantom{}_A H_{n+1}^2-\phantom{}_A H_{n}^2 = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\left(\phantom{}_A H_n+\phantom{}_A H_{n+1}\right). $$
That gives $g(x)$ as a combination of $\text{Li}_2(x),\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)$ and $\log(1+x)\log\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)$.

With some extra work, the original limit is converted into a polylogarithmic integral.